# Background Image width shall overflow, Fix height

Tags: html, css, resize, height, overflow

I want to set height 100% and width overflow to an image, so that on every screen the TOP Menu (Red Buttons) and the Footer Menu can be reached easily.

Left hand side and right hand site can overflow.

I tried

```
.stretch {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Withouth success. And changing values makes the image fullscreen and has not the desired effect.

Any Ideas?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H75BT/2/

---

**Edit:**

From Bigood's answer, I need this one to be centered : http://jsfiddle.net/H75BT/1/

Comment: Reproduce your bug on jsFiddle. We don't know your code..

Comment: A screen shot is no good here. You need to reproduce your issue in some form of code. As it is this is impossible to answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H75BT/ Here it is. You have to Pull the window horizontally. I dont wann to have height overflow

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear. [Is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/H75BT/1/)

Comment: yes!!! BUT now the Image only disappears at the right hand side. IT should move out on the left hand and right hand side. Do you understand? http://bockt.de/link/screen.jpg <-- The Content should stay in middle of the Window.

Comment: @DanielMcDonald Please see my edited answer, I think I achieved what you wanted.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, for future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a 100% height on html & body, and define that your `.stretch` will adapt its height to the height of the body, and recalculate its width to keep the proportions :

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden; /* Add this to prevent the body to adapt its width if you need */
}


.stretch {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H75BT/2/)

---

### Edit

You can make it centered by using CSS's `background`:

```
.stretch {
    background-image: url("http://bockt.de/link/home.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-origin: padding-box;
}
```

With a `<div class="stretch"></div>`.

[Centered image demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H75BT/4/)